# Python: extract floats from txt files

Tags: python, extract, txt

I have this txt file:

```
TP 0.8329
```

And i tried to extract that float after "TP" using the following code:

```
def definir_operacao():
    end = 0
    oper = []
    for x in range(len(lines[0])):
        if(lines[0][x] == " "):
            end += 1
        elif(end == 1):
            oper.append(int(lines[0][x]))
    str2 = ''.join(oper)
    return str2


ci = definir_operacao()
print(ci)
```

But i get a empty variable as response, so i guess i'm making something wrong, can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you include the complete code you are working on? Including the part where you read the file.

Comment: if this is some kind of config file meant to be read by code, use a python file, yaml, ini, or other "code friendly" format.  If it is a spreadsheet, use pandas.  Reading data is a common task, so the first thing to find are the shiny tools that already exist to make your life easier

Answer (score 0):

Just do this one-liner instead:

```
ci = float(lines[0].split()[1])
```

And now:

```
print(ci)
```

Would give:

```
0.8329
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking that whether you get an `" "`, and if so you're appending the exact same `" "` with `oper`. See this segment again:

```
if(lines[0][x] == " "):
        end += 1
elif(end == 1):
        oper.append(int(lines[0][x]))
```

That is why you're getting empty as response.

just split the line on the basis of `" "` and take the second value from the splitting result. Don't forget to cast it to float. That will give you what you want.

```
res = float(lines[0].split(" ")[1])
```

You can just use split() too as @U11-Forward mentioned, because default separator is whitespace.